# In what systems are opening 4 card majors ok?

Tags: openings, duplicate-bridge

I had several 4 card majors yesterday.  Is there a system that opens 4 card majors.  Partner says no, only in response.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of systems that open on 4-cards, I myself play one, and that is not very uncommon here. 4-card systems are commonly used to teach Bridge. Most people prefer 5-card major though, and 4-card major feels outdated these days.

A couple of the more well-known 4-card systems are

- [ACOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acol)
- [Standard American, originnal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_American)

Comment: "Most people" depends very much where you are, and "feels outdated" is entirely subjective; I know several people who have abandoned 5-card majors as obsolete. Good answer though.

Comment: @TimLymington I totally agree with both of observations. However, in the netherlands this is without exception the prevailing opinion, broadcast by the national Bridge Association themselves.